# clipping a DIV in HTML without canvas element

Tags: html, animation, canvas, css, clipping

I'm working on an HTML+Javascript Page flip effect.
I want this to accomplish this without the HTML5 Canvas element so that I can use this with text/forms etc.

This is what I have hacked together so far(webkit browsers,im using chrome 12):
[JSFIDDLE: Page Flip](http://jsfiddle.net/gjg6s/)

Preview:

[image: The overlapping region is the one to SHOW]

What I want to do is not show the regions of the red rectangle outside of the blue rectangle.
My problem Lies in the MASKING / CLIPPING of the overlapping region (the purple area).
I tried to embed the page (red) div within the mask (blue) div and set `overflow : hidden` 
but the problem was whenever the mask (blue) rotated, the page (red) rotated as well and the calculations were leading nowhere to correct with an offset.

Are there any other ways I can clip this region?

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate and implement counter rotation for the inner div to offset the rotation of the outer/masking div. Here's [an example from our Sencha Animator demos](http://dev.sencha.com/animator/demos/pageflip/):

I'm sure you've seen Roman Cortes's original CSS pageflip - whose method we copied for the demo who uses a common fixed rotation point for both divs.

Comment: That would be great for a fixed path page flip. I'm not sure how to make them rotate with a common point though.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's non-trivial...let me noodle

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly, you want to have the (blue) div above the (red) div? If that's correct then add a `z-index` property to both and have the (blue) div `z-index` higher than that of the (red) div.

**Update:** It may be worth looking into the CSS `clip` property because your (red) div is already positioned absolutely. The only problem then would be that your (red) div, I believe, would need to be inside of the (blue) div.

Comment: no, I would like to NOT SHOW the red part outside of the blue